# Firebase dataSnapshot.getValue( .class) Crash

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, location

I need help with my code, I can save to my database. But when i go to get value to my app i get crash. Its my code.

```
      alanRef.child("").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


  

                Marcadores_info_carga group = dataSnapshot.getValue(Marcadores_info_carga.class);
                System.out.println(group);

   


                }
                

public class Marcadores_info_carga {

        // Se definen las variable para enviar
        private int nroreclamocarga;
        private String titulocarga;
        private String informacioncarga;
        private String direccioncarga;
        private double latitudcarga;
        private double longitudcarga;


        public Marcadores_info_carga() {
        }

        public Marcadores_info_carga(int nroreclamocarga, String titulocarga, String informacioncarga, String direccioncarga, double latitudcarga, double longitudcarga){

            this.nroreclamocarga = nroreclamocarga;
            this.titulocarga = titulocarga;
            this.informacioncarga = informacioncarga;
            this.direccioncarga = direccioncarga;
            this.latitudcarga = latitudcarga;
            this.longitudcarga = longitudcarga;
        }


        public int getNroreclamocarga() {

            return nroreclamocarga;
        }

        public String getTitulocarga() {

            return titulocarga;
        }
        public String getInformacioncarga() {

            return informacioncarga;
        }


        public String getDireccioncarga() {

            return direccioncarga;
        }

        public double getLatitud() {

           return latitudcarga;
       }


        public double getLongitud() {

            return longitudcarga;
       }


    }
```

I get crash when this update. I was trying and debugging and connecting well to the database but I did not get it to work

## UPDATED:

```
MY LOGCAT LOGCAT:
```

```html
 03-29 23:09:06.223 397-414/? W/ActivityManager: Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{4a9a09e4 u0 com.example.lays.myapplication/.MapsActivity t63 f}
03-29 23:09:06.233 697-697/? D/FirebaseApp: Notifying background state change listeners.
03-29 23:09:06.253 697-697/? W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-29 23:09:06.703 397-520/? W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger: setKernelCountSet(10037, 0) failed with errno -13
03-29 23:09:16.713 397-414/? W/ActivityManager: Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{4a9a09e4 u0 com.example.lays.myapplication/.MapsActivity t63 f}
03-29 23:09:38.903 683-689/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 396K, 13% free 3328K/3796K, paused 0ms+0ms, total 2ms
```

MY DATABASE:

```html
    {
  "direccion" : "213",
  "informacion" : "123",
  "latitud" : -60.726239047944546,
  "longitud" : -32.886316425298524,
  "nroreclamo" : "213",
  "titulo" : "2132"
}
```

Comment: Can you add your schema for the database?

Comment: please post your logcat

Comment: Ready! i updated the post!

Comment: Please post the full stack trace for the exception that you get when the app crashes. Other parts of the logcat are not nearly as useful.

Answer (score 1):

Change the 'private' fields to 'public' in your JavaBeans,and change your javabean's fields:

```
ppublic class Marcadores_info_carga {

/**
 * direccion : 213
 * informacion : 123
 * latitud : 60.726239047944546
 * longitud : -32.886316425298524
 * nroreclamo : 213
 * titulo : 2132
 */

public String direccion;
public String informacion;
public double latitud;
public double longitud;
public String nroreclamo;
public String titulo;

public String getDireccion() {
    return direccion;
}

public void setDireccion(String direccion) {
    this.direccion = direccion;
}

public String getInformacion() {
    return informacion;
}

public void setInformacion(String informacion) {
    this.informacion = informacion;
}

public double getLatitud() {
    return latitud;
}

public void setLatitud(double latitud) {
    this.latitud = latitud;
}

public double getLongitud() {
    return longitud;
}

public void setLongitud(double longitud) {
    this.longitud = longitud;
}

public String getNroreclamo() {
    return nroreclamo;
}

public void setNroreclamo(String nroreclamo) {
    this.nroreclamo = nroreclamo;
}

public String getTitulo() {
    return titulo;
}

public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
    this.titulo = titulo;
}
}
```

UPDATE:
Your java bean not match the database json field:

```
{  
"direccion" : "213",  
"informacion" : "123",  
"latitud" : 60.726239047944546,  
"longitud" : -32.886316425298524,  
"nroreclamo" : "213",  
"titulo" : "2132"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answerme, Ready! but i get same crash, with breakpoint in:                 Marcadoresinfocarga group = dataSnapshot.getValue(Marcadoresinfocarga.class);

I get all struct from database but i get crash too. http://i.imgur.com/iXA6UXc.png